# Avoiding overlap of elements inside a col?

Tags: html, css, mdbootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm currently messing a bit around with the bootstrap grid system, I kinda get to understand it, but if I change the width of the elements inside a col, then it's overlapping when I resize the browser.

Just trying to make cards responsive when resizing the browser, but I want to change the size of the cards aswell without making them overlap.

[This is how it looks like when I change the width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SywPZ.png)

[This is how it's supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpjNu.png)

that's how I do it right now:

```
<main>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-4">
                <div class="card card-cascade dashboard-card bg-lightblue">
                    <div class="data mt-4 ml-3">
                        <div class="button px-2">
                            <a class="btn-floating btn-lg float-right"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <h4 class="text-white mb-2">1</h4>
                        <p class="text-white">Test Card</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4">
                <div class="card card-cascade dashboard-card bg-lightblue">
                    <div class="data mt-4 ml-3">
                        <div class="button px-2">
                            <a class="btn-floating btn-lg float-right"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <h4 class="text-white mb-2">0</h4>
                        <p class="text-white">Test Card 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4">
                <div class="card card-cascade dashboard-card bg-lightblue">
                    <div class="data mt-4 ml-3">
                        <div class="button px-2">
                            <a class="btn-floating btn-lg float-right"><i class="fas fa-ticket"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <h4 class="text-white mb-2">0</h4>
                        <p class="text-white">Test Card 3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Kinda stuck on that.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: doesn't change anything, tried also to apply it to col- class but only makes it not resizable

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 4 or bootstrap 5 (alpha)? One of the tags should be removed.

Comment: I'm currently using bootstrap 5 (alpha) with mdbootstrap

Comment: Do you have other CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Give col-xl-4 class:

1. width of (94/3)%
2. padding left of 1%
3. padding right of 1%

Give container-fluid class:

1. padding left of 20px
2. padding right of 20px